# How to make responsive video in a frame?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on the responsive version of client's website and I stumbled upon this issue - when I make smaller the browser window, the youtube video is not centered - the **padding-right: 10px;** is ignored - why?

How could I fix that?

Here is the CSS that I use for the border around youtube video:

```
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you put `overflow: hidden;`?

Use div to center an element for example:

```
#video
{

    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
}
#main_video
{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<div id="main_video">
<div id="video">
    [example]
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because when I remove the `overflow: hidden;`, then the video width will not be reduced.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same problem.

Comment: Try add `position: relative;` on div on `#video`

Comment: Ok. Let's explain. You have a YT embed source. On border area you need spacing but it will going position not fixed. First, you need set-up your video in width/height space (detect which size is using via firebug). Then on outer embed you put new DIV element to centering video object and setup a size. I think due to picture, a video is larger than on div is defined. So you can't get a more space because a video should be smaller to fit inner area of `#main_video`

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the video not resizing correctly is probably because of the embed code that you're using, which typically specifies the exact dimension of the `<iframe>` element, making it non-responsive towards layout changes or resize events.

There is a nifty jQuery plugin out there that does exactly that - http://fitvidsjs.com/

Alternatively, you can always write your own simple jQuery function ([see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/WbJYP/)) :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $w = $(window),
        $vids = $("iframe[src*='youtube'], iframe[src*='vimeo']");

    // Store video aspect ratio
    $vids.each(function() {
        var aspectRatio = $(this).width() / $(this).height();
        $(this).attr("data-aspect-ratio", aspectRatio);
    });

    $w.resize(function() {
        // Set video width fluidly
        $vids.each(function() {
           $(this).width($(this).parent().width()); 
           $(this).height(Math.floor($(this).width() / $(this).data("aspect-ratio")));
        });
    }).resize();
});
```

It is probably a good idea to throttle or debounce the resize function ([see link here](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)), because when you have too many videos on the same page and when you resize the page, you will fire off a chain of resize() which will definitely have an impact on browser performance.